# How can I draw a rectangle that has a single concave face?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I wanted to draw this using Photoshop:

[image: cartoon drawing]

However as you can see the dark green rectangle is not a perfect rectangle. It's rounded at the bottom but I don't know how to do this.

[image: cartoon drawing]

I drew a normal rectangle then subtracted an ellipse from it, but I wanted to know if that's the correct way to do things or not... Subtracting forms with Photoshop CS6 isn't precise, or I used it wrong. I looked on the web and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the rectangle tool <kbd>U</kbd>.
2. Draw the shape.  Get the pen tool out and "add anchor point tool" under the pen tool options <kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Place it in the bottom center of the rectangle.
4. Get the direct selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> and click on the new anchor point and drag upwards.

[image]

Comment: Just to add to this since I get the feeling Namrouch might not know -- you can also use guides to assist. Show your rulers (Ctrl/Cmd + R) and click and drag out from the rulers to create guides. That will help with centering and such.